# Why some emojis in SQL Server are equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unicode, emoji

I using SQL Server 2016 and have one database with Arabic_100_CI_AS and I inserted apple emojis to my database but some of emojis are equals in condtions but other emojis are not equal

```
select 1
where N'⛑' = N'✅'
```

or

```
select 1
where N'✊' = N'⭐️'
```

This emojis are equals:

✊
✋
⛑
⭐️
✨
⛅️
⛈
⛄️
⚽️
⚾️
⛳️
⛸
⛷
⛹️
⛵️
⛴
⛽️
⛲️
⛱
⛰
⛺
⛪️
⛩
⏱
⏲
⏰
⏳
⛏
⛓
⛎
❌
⭕️
⛔️
❗️
❕
❓
❔
✅
❎
⏸
⏯
⏹
⏺
⏭
⏮
⏩
⏪
⏫
⏬
➕
➖
➗
➰
➿
⬛️
⬜️

Comment: Are there collation settings in play here?

Comment: Try a binary collation. These also compare equal to empty string so have no weights.

Comment: `⭐️` is actually 2 codepoints:  ` 2B50   WHITE MEDIUM STAR` and `FE0F   VARIATION SELECTOR-16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Mr.** Martin Smith suggest try to collate them with help of `Arabic, binary sort`

```
select 1
where N'⛑' = N'✅' collate Arabic_BIN
```

or

```
select 1
where N'✊' = N'⭐️' collate Arabic_BIN
```

**To answer your question :** 
                 The equality of your emojis are dependent on collation.