# Not recognize some of Emojis in sql server with Arabic_BIN collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unicode, emoji

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and my database has the `Arabic_100_CI_AS` collation. I inserted apple emojis in my database, but some of the emojis are equal in comparisons while other emojis are not equal. I resolved this problem with `collate Arabic_BIN` and I asked in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194048/why-some-emojis-in-sql-server-are-equal/)

But I have new problem with `Arabic_BIN` Collation:
For example I can't recognize some of emojis with this query:

```
SELECT [EMoji_ID]
FROM [Emojies].[dbo].[Emojies]
WHERE Emoji_Emoji = N'❤' COLLATE Arabic_BIN
```

The above query returns any ID, but this query returns ID:

```
SELECT [EMoji_ID]
FROM [Emojies].[dbo].[Emojies]
WHERE Emoji_Emoji = N'❤'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with `COLLATE Arabic_100_CI_AS_SC`

Comment: It also works with its counterpart `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC`.